# Bean validation configuration not picked up if placed in library jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, websphere-liberty

I'm using Bean Validation 1.1 in a Java EE 7 web application. Validation works fine but I've trouble getting it to work on both Wildfly and Liberty.

I've configured a custom message interpolator via validation.xml which is placed in a library jar:

```
ROOT
|-- WEB-INF
    |-- lib
        |-- my-validation.jar
            |-- mypackage
                |-- MyMessageInterpolator.class
            |-- META-INF
                |--validation.xml
```

When deployed to Wildfly 14 everything works as expected. On Liberty 19 however `MyMessageInterpolator` is found, **but not invoked** during validation (e.g. when using `@Valid` in a REST resource).

I then moved `validation.xml` directly into the web app (without moving the message interpolator itself):

```
ROOT
|-- WEB-INF
    |-- classes
        |-- META-INF
            |-- validation.xml
    |-- lib
        |-- my-validation.jar
            |-- mypackage
                |-- MyMessageInterpolator.class
```

This is working on Liberty but I'd expect it to work also when `validation.xml` is placed in a library jar. The [Bean Validation 1.1 spec](https://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-config) says:

> Unless explicitly ignored [...], a `Configuration` takes into account the configuration available in `META-INF/validation.xml`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Andy's answer for the default behavior of Liberty. However there is a property, `com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.allowMultipleConfigsPerApp`, that can be configured to get the behavior you're looking for. By setting `com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.allowMultipleConfigsPerApp=false` (the default is true), the entire application will be scanned for a single `META-INF/validation.xml` and applied to all modules. The downside of this is there can only be one validation.xml defined in your application. If more than one is found a deployment error will occur.

See the following links for more details on setting this property:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html#rwlp_restrict__BeanvalidationFeatureRestrict

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43130

Comment: Setting that property to false solved my problem but I still don't get why. In my understanding the file WEB-INF/lib/my-validation.jar/META-INF/validation.xml is as much in the web module's classpath as WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/validation.xml so it should be used. Even the description of PI43130 doesn't seem to really fit as it's about _multiple_ validation.xml files in the application(!) classpath. However **I do have only one** validation.xml in the classpath, but it's ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working as intended. The BeanValidation spec works in a JavaEE or JavaSE environment, so when it says `META-INF/validation.xml`, that's usually relative to `WEB-INF/classes/` in a JavaEE environment.

For comparison, if you want to use JPA's persistence.xml in a .war module, you need to put it at `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`. Same with CDI's beans.xml, which goes in `WEB-INF/classes/beans.xml` in a .war module.

It may be allowed in other places too, but from what I have seen supporting other locations are not defined by the spec.